# How to change the Xamarin Android Player screen size

Tags: android, xamarin, emulation, screen-size

I'm using Xamarin Forms on Visual Studio. But I have problem with the project screen size when I debug. My screen resolution is 1366x768 and there is not an option to change the emulator resolution on its settings.

How can I change the Xamarin Android Player screen size ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [the blogpost](https://blog.xamarin.com/live-from-dotnetconf-cycle-7-xamarin-studio-6-and-more/) Xamarin Android Player is deprecated

> To streamline development setup on Mac OS X, we have introduced a brand new universal installer. This will not only handle updating to the latest version of Xamarin, but also will setup the new and improved Android Emulators from Google, based on x86 HAXM, that are now 10 times faster then before! If you are on Windows using Visual Studio be sure to checkout the Hyper-V enabled [Visual Studio Emulators for Android](https://beta.visualstudio.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/) that make debugging Android apps a joy. With these enhancements to the Android emulators for both Mac and PC the Xamarin Android Player is now officially deprecated. We hope that you love this new setup process and the new emulators.

You could just use [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) if you are too lazy(like me) to set up Google's Android emulators.

Comment: I had been tried Genymotion, I have created a virtual device and could be able to debug with it but I wanted to test it, then I have restarted the Windows, but now the Visual Studio doesn't detect Genymotion. So now the emulator doesn't launch... although I have started it. What could I miss?

Comment: Do you have emulated device running? you should add new device and start it https://i.imgur.com/eLFKa1S.png after that it should appear in visual studio

Comment: I have added the new virtual device in Genymoetion, and started already but the VS doesn't see it, as I say.

Comment: Visual studio should have `Android Device Monitor` in `Tools`. open it and see if there are any devices visible.I'm on mac but it should look exactly like this: https://i.imgur.com/mHEzI36.png

Comment: VS says "The item does not support previewing" when I select it.

Comment: Can you make a screenshot?

Comment: I have restarted Windows and its okey now, `Android Device Monitor` opened. Its screenshot: http://prnt.sc/c998ip

Comment: your device is listed there, it means `Genymotion` is working fine. Theres something wrong with visual studio.

Thing you can try:

1. Check if minimum api level of your android project doesn't exceed the api level of the Genymotion device.

2. Right mouse click on Android project and  select `Set As Startup Project`

Comment: Yes I had set as startup but how can I check the api level ?

Comment: go to project properties and check these https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/understanding_android_api_levels/